# Codeigniter: fatal error call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I just changed my server and experience these errors below:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /home/blacktwitter/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 126
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/blacktwitter/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:126)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 564

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 126

Backtrace:
```

Website is in Codeigniter. It works on one server very well and on the local machine too. But when I upload that website at the new server I have that errors. Of course I changed important parameters like database connection, base_url() etc.

I was suspicious about database, but I have created a new database and user etc. and changed connection info.

Why does this happen? It will be helpful to know if it is a bug at the server or at the website. Also when I create some index.html with some test code everything is fine.

Comment: Check the phpinfo() for the new server and make sure mysqli is installed.

Comment: did you solve the it?

Comment: @hybrid i dont know why you open bounty for this. This comes cz of user mistake. As well if there is an bug  we cant check it. Cz no codes are here

Comment: I would suggest you to reinstall mysql and add make needed changes in php.ini Coz maybe some files are missing/not properly added in the installed mysql application.

Answer (score 38):

It is not a bug in your application, it is just a missing driver, so, you have couple of options...

Go to your php init and uncomment the following:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

If not, try installing it at your server, it varies depending on your distribution.

Try installing  `php5-mysqlnd`

If you cannot do it by hosting restrictions then just move to mysql driver (wont need to change other configurations or queries in CodeIgniter or anything else...)

like this (at your config file)

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; (you might have mysqli now)
```

Comment: with php 5.4 or above mysqlnd seems to be a default option ? [mysqlnd](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlnd.install.html) [php-mysqlnd](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/)

Comment: Nice, this was the solution for me. In my case I'm running centos 7 and I had to restart the httpd service to get it working. "sudo yum systemctl restart httpd"

Answer (score 28):

I just had this issue on a `ubuntu16.04`, `php7.1` install with `Codeigniter 3`.

Solution was simple (if hard to find!)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

I realised that the `mysql*.ini` files where missing from the `etc/php/7.1/mods-available` directory.  Not sure how it happened, but that worked for me.

If you use 7.2, simply type `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql`

Comment: mmm... The question was asked on november 9, 2015 and [PHP 7 was released on december 17, 2015.](http://php.net/archive/2015.php) I'm sure there was another solution at this time.

Comment: I think it's not important, I was looking for this solution, and the versions are obviously updated from time to time.

Answer (score 15):

Use this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.*-mysqli
```

or

```
sudo phpenmod mysqli
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 7):

This is actually not a CodeIgniter issue but PHP installation issue.

I have installed PHP5.6 in my Linux server and is having a hard time following the googled solutions of using the ff command in order to install the missing mysqli_extension in PHP.

What I tried is but is returning the warning message:  Unable to locate package php5-mysqli

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli
```

However, my php version is 5.6 so I tried

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysqli
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is php's mysql extension might not have installed, if you are using php 7, just issue the below command and install the extension,

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: After doing it you must restart mysql server. - sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 2):

Open the folder where you have installed PHP, Edit `php.ini` file
**uncomment** this line:
`extension=php_mysqli.dll`

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you can install MySQL driver extension.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

In Windows with XAMPP, the driver has already saved in **ext** directory, but you need to enable it in **php.ini**. You need to **uncomment** this line:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

You also need to check the extension directory location in **php.ini**. I use absolute path (not relative path) declaration to make it works.

```
extension_dir="your\absolute\path\to\xampp\php\ext"
```

For example,

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the difference is not that big but for the ones who are running CentOS:

```
sudo yum install php-mysqli
sudo systemctl status httpd
```

We are installing the `mysqli` extension using `yum` and then restarting our `httpd` server for the changes to take effect, and in case you are not using `httpd` just replace `httpd` for the name of your service.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a missing line in **php.ini** that solved it, as I copied another **php.ini** file to my **XAMPP** installation. 
Worth checking if the line: "`extension=php_mysqli.dll`" exist (if running Windows, but this isn't applicable for OP, as it's a Linux system), or if the "`extension_dir`" exists and is correct.

Comment: I am using web server (cPanel) and mysqli is installed. I tried removing it and adding it also. Still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

1、apt-get install (yum, compile install whatever) php5-mysqlnd extension.

2、if not work, make sure mysqli is loaded

```
    root@x19-ws07-1:/etc/php5/apache2# cat /proc/31682/maps | grep mysql
```

if is loaded, you can see:

```
    7f2cd3266000-7f2cd3285000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 864561                     /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so
    7f2cd69ef000-7f2cd6a2e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 864559                     /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqlnd.so
```

3、if not loaded use php --ini to find config file

```
    xxxx@xxxx:~$ php --ini
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/apache2
    Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
    Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
```

4、if not config extension, config like this and remember restart your web server

```
    xxxx@xxxxx:~$ cat /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    ; configuration for php MySQL module
    ; priority=20
    extension=mysqli.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried, comment out below line in `/etc/php/cli/php.ini` file.

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04  on AWS-EC2 instances and PHP 7.0. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Windows I had all the necessary extensions uncommented, but it wasn't loading them. Then, I checked the extension directory variable in php.ini and it was as `"ext"`, but then I remembered I'd had a similar problem previously. So what I did was basically put the explicit directory. Something like this:

`extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"`

Of course the specific ext directory depends entirely on your own setup and locations.

After updating the php.ini file you just have to restart Apache to apply the changes.

If you installed your Apache manually (not using pre-packaged solutions like XAMPP or WAMPP) you just have to use these commands in either a Command Prompt or a Powershell with administrator rights.

`net stop Apache2.4`

`net start Apache2.4`

Answer (score -1):

If your webserver is running with a lower version of MySQL, then you will get this error as MySQLi is not supported in MySQL < 4.1.3

It is highly recommended to go with MySQLi instead of going back to MySQL extension.

[More info on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: I checked the version.It is the latest one

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you do the following:

change:

```
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
```

to:

```
'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
'dbprefix' => '',
```

in `database.php` file.