# Getting mysqli driver not found error in PCF for a Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy Codeigniter application in PCF. CF Push was success but i got the below error.

```
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: /home/vcap/app/htdocs/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

File: /home/vcap/app/htdocs/application/controllers/Dashboard.php
Line: 8
Function: __construct

File: /home/vcap/app/htdocs/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Does anyone how to deploy a php application with MySQLi driver enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter: fatal error call to undefined function mysqli\_init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612956/codeigniter-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-init)

Comment: No. This question is related to Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The extension isn't loaded. By default, the PHP Buildpack doesn't load any extensions.

The Cloud Foundry PHP Buildpack will ensure that extensions you require are loaded but you need to tell it to load them. There are two options for telling the buildpack which extensions to load:

1. Composer. If [you `require` your PHP extensions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links), the buildpack will see this and automatically enable them. Ex: `"require": "ext-mysqli"`.
2. [Buildpack config file](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html#php-extensions). Create `.bp-config/php/php.ini.d/FILE-NAME.ini`, where `FILE-NAME` is anything you want, I typically just call it `extensions.ini`. This file is read by PHP, so you can add any valid php.ini config, but for our purposes here you'd add `extension=mysqli.so` (or whatever extensions you want to load).

After making the changes from 1 or 2, just `cf push` your app again. The buildpack will run and it will enable the extensions you requested.